# Selecting children of an iframe from the parent of said iframe via css

Tags: css, iframe, stylesheet, selector

Is there a simple way to do (what any normal person would assume) this does:

```
html{
    background-color:orange;
}
html iframe html {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

without breaking my stylesheet into two?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. The `iframe` is an entirely separate, encapsulated document.

The best you can do is embed the same style sheet in both documents, give the iframe document a class or ID:

```
<body class="iframe">
```

and do a

```
body.iframe {
    background-color:orange;
}
```